# Dropdown Arrow in Menu disappeared on wordpress what to do now?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

you can see the attached below image the moment i place cursor on home, dropdown menu works but down arrow symbol does not work or showing please help me out ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add +/- on `li` with childrens.
Use http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/ for generate arrow symbol in CSS

```
li.menu-item-has-children > a:after{
    content : '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 100px 0 100px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
li.menu-item-has-children:hover  > a:after{
    border-width: 0 100px 100px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
```

Comment: but i want arrow symbol, not +,- operator @Sco

Comment: i update my code with arrow in css 

Tools :  http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: into styles.css on your theme

Comment: one more question, follow the link to answer please help me out with this also         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66458654/showing-theme-name-in-every-link-everywhere